# Как объединить два запроса?

Tags: python, sqlite

как построить запрос , чтобы `id` равнялся значению `page` с таблицы `tmp` где `user_id = 19`

```
...
c.execute('SELECT * FROM Сontent WHERE id =  # ?  ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, есть 2 таблицы:

1. **my_table** с полями *id*, ...
2. **tmp** с полями *page*, *user_id*, ...

Тогда запрос такой:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table join tmp on my_table.id = tmp.page
WHERE tmp.user_id = 19
```

Answer (score -1):

Например, так:

```
select * from tmp, Content where Content.id=tmp.page and user_id=19;
```